# Selenium - Page Object Model vs Defining public static final

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium we can maintain the Object Repository as Page Object Model. But we can maintain OR through a separate class by defining variables as public static final and use in the other classes whenever required.

for e.g.

```
package ObjectRepository;

public class OR_SFStandard 
{ 
   public static final String NewBtn = "//a[@title='New']";
}
```

and use the same in code as

```
package common;
import ObjectRepository;

public class Deal 
{
    public void newDeal(WebDriver driver)
    {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepository.NewBtn)).click();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand the difference and what is better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you question, and based on my experience as I have used both. I would recommend to use standard practice of POM. Main feature of POM is maintainance  would be easy.

> You have Locators on page object so you can see them page wise and fix
>   in case of any issue. Common locators are part of base page object so
>   you can get all common locators on Base page object.

In case if OR  managed in separate class  then

> Suppose if you have have 200 test cases, 40-50 Page object and you are
>   keeping all locators (say 500) in One class then it would be very
>   difficult to manage and debug to fix issue. It will create confusion too.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that it is the matter of preferences. I like to have all related data in one POP class. Otehrs would prefer to have the distinct file with those.

Some may think that repository allows them to reuse the elements, that are shared across different pages, limiting the duplication. But that should not be the case. If you have to share the elements between POMs, that means you have implemented it in wrong way. Even when it comes to elements like footers, menus etc.

In that case you should to think about [Feature Object Patter](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/feature-object-pattern/) and implement all actions and OR there.